# How would I decode this with lua?

Tags: lua, cryptography

So I want to make a decode option for this but my attempt at it doesn't work

Encode:

```
local function enc(MSG)
    local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X","Y", "Z", " ", ".", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_", "*", "'", "^", "~", "!"}
    local resourcesT = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "⛹", "", "㊗️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☁️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛄️","", "↪️", "", "", "❗️", "", "", "", "", "️", "", "", "", "⚫️", "", "⭕️", "", "☣", "", "⏯", "", "", "", "", "⌛️", "⌨", "", "", "⏫", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#️⃣", "", "", "✖️", ""}
    local finalstring = ""
    MSG:gsub(".", function(c)
        for i, v in ipairs(resources) do
                if v == c then
                    finalstring = finalstring .. tostring(resourcesT[i])
                end
            end
    end)
    return finalstring
end
local Enc = enc("Hello World")
```

Here is my attempt at a decode but it doesn't work:

```
local function dec(MSG)
    local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X","Y", "Z", " ", ".", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_", "*", "'", "^", "~", "!"}
    local resourcesT = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "⛹", "", "㊗️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☁️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛄️","", "↪️", "", "", "❗️", "", "", "", "", "️", "", "", "", "⚫️", "", "⭕️", "", "☣", "", "⏯", "", "", "", "", "⌛️", "⌨", "", "", "⏫", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#️⃣", "", "", "✖️", ""}
    local finalstring = ""
    MSG:gsub(".", function(c)
        for i, v in ipairs(resourcesT) do
                if v == c then
                    finalstring = finalstring .. tostring(resources[i])
                end
            end
    end)
    return finalstring
end
local Dec = dec("Hello World")
```

Can someone please fix this decoder for me?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work, as you're attempting to match a single byte (using `.` pattern), but all those emojis are multi-byte characters (assuming UTF-8 encoding), so you either need to use utf8 library to match those code points properly or replace the `.` match with something like `.[\128-\191]*`. You also need to decode something other than `Hello Worlds`, as these characters are not present in the `resourcesT` table.

This prints `Hello World` for me:

```
local function dec(MSG)
    local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X","Y", "Z", " ", ".", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_", "*", "'", "^", "~", "!"}
    local resourcesT = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "⛹", "", "㊗️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☁️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛄️","", "↪️", "", "", "❗️", "", "", "", "", "️", "", "", "", "⚫️", "", "⭕️", "", "☣", "", "⏯", "", "", "", "", "⌛️", "⌨", "", "", "⏫", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#️⃣", "", "", "✖️", ""}
    local finalstring = ""
    MSG:gsub(".[\128-\191]*", function(c)
        for i, v in ipairs(resourcesT) do
                if v == c then
                    finalstring = finalstring .. tostring(resources[i])
                end
            end
    end)
    return finalstring
end
local Dec = dec("")
print(Dec)
```